# Github Actions - Compare and find differences between two OAS V3 files

Tags: automation, diff, openapi, github-actions, human-readable

Suppose you are given two OpenApi Specification (OAS) V3 files :

- original-spec.yaml : The original spec
- modified-spec.yaml : The modified ( with enhancement / breaking changes / etc )
  ( an example of both files is available on https://gist.github.com/jy95/d7b53648eb756547eb67fd0db962f68d )

I would like to find a CLI tool that will generates an human readable report
( that I could ,for example, upload it in a PR comment with [PR Comment from File](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pr-comment-from-file)
 )

My requirements are the following ones :

- no technical restriction
  ( you are free to use any programming language library as long as it
  works , including using a OAS to Swagger v2 converter if needed )
- human readable / comprehensible
  ( it should be clear so that people that don't know OAS aren't lost )
- maintained
  ( not mandatory but it is better )

Currently I found these projects on the web :
 - [openapi-diff](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/openapi-diff/src/master/)
 - [quen2404/openapi-diff](https://github.com/quen2404/openapi-diff)
 - [Azure/openapi-diff](https://github.com/Azure/openapi-diff)
 - ...

( others undoubtedly exist: I leave it to you to find some / or to help me pick one that's good enough... )

Here is the start of a Github workflow to help you kickstart :

```
name: API Breaking Changes
# Everyone is happy with breaking changes ^^
on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build-report:
    needs: build-oas-artefacts
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download OAS file from SOURCE branch
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: original-spec.yaml
      - name: Download OAS file from TARGET branch
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: modified-spec.yaml
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer :

```
    name: API Breaking Changes
    # Everyone is happy with breaking changes ^^
    on:
      pull_request:

    jobs:
      build-oas-artefacts:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
            with:
              node-version: '12.x'
          - name: Install required tools
            run: |
              npm install speccy -g
              npm install -g @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli@1.0.10-4.2.3
          - name: Set up env variables
            run:  |
              echo "::set-env name=CURRENT_BRANCH::$(echo ${{ github.head_ref }} | sed 's|.*/||')"
              echo "::set-env name=TARGET_BRANCH::$(echo ${{ github.base_ref }} | sed 's|.*/||')"
          - name: Clone repository in branch ${{ env.TARGET_BRANCH }}
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
            with:
              path: 'A'
              ref: ${{ github.base_ref }}
          - name: Clone repository in branch ${{ env.CURRENT_BRANCH }}
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
            with:
              path: 'B'
          - name: Check if OAS from ${{ env.CURRENT_BRANCH }} is valid
            run: |
              npx openapi-generator validate -i B/api.yml
          - name: Check if OAS from ${{ env.TARGET_BRANCH }} is valid
            run: |
              npx openapi-generator validate -i A/api.yml
          - name: Build OAS specifications
            run: |
              npx speccy resolve A/api.yml -o original-spec.yaml
              npx speccy resolve B/api.yml -o modified-spec.yaml
          - name: Upload single OAS file from ${{ env.TARGET_BRANCH }}
            uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: original-spec.yaml
              path: original-spec.yaml
          - name: Upload single OAS file from ${{ env.CURRENT_BRANCH }}
            uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: modified-spec.yaml
              path: modified-spec.yaml
      build-report:
        needs: build-oas-artefacts
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
            with:
              node-version: '13.x'
          - name: Install required tools
            run: |
              npm install openapi-diff -g
          - name: Download OAS file from SOURCE branch
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: original-spec.yaml
              path: specs/
          - name: Download OAS file from TARGET branch
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: modified-spec.yaml
              path: specs/
          - name: Set up env variables
            run:  |
              echo "::set-env name=ORIGIN_SPEC::$(echo "$(pwd)/specs/original-spec.yaml" )"
              echo "::set-env name=MODIFIED_SPEC::$(echo "$(pwd)/specs/modified-spec.yaml" )"
              echo "::set-env name=SPECS_LOG::$(echo "$(pwd)/breaking-changes.log" )"
              echo "::set-env name=JSON_DIFF_FILE::$(echo "$(pwd)/breaking-changes.json" )"
              echo "::set-env name=GH_COMMENT_FILE::$(echo "$(pwd)/Github-comment.md" )"
    # See : https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/issues/14
          - name: Restore permissions
            run: |
              chmod -R 777 ${{ env.ORIGIN_SPEC }}
              chmod -R 777 ${{ env.MODIFIED_SPEC }}
          - name: Generate report
            run: |
              openapi-diff ${{ env.ORIGIN_SPEC }} ${{ env.MODIFIED_SPEC }} | tee ${{ env.SPECS_LOG }}
              sed -n '1!p' ${{ env.SPECS_LOG }} > ${{ env.JSON_DIFF_FILE }}
          - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: openapi-diff.json
              path: breaking-changes.json
          - name: Prepare comment on Github PR
            run: |
              sed -n '1p' ${{ env.SPECS_LOG }} >> ${{ env.GH_COMMENT_FILE }}
              printf "\n\n\`\`\`yaml\n" >> ${{ env.GH_COMMENT_FILE }}
              sed -n '1!p' ${{ env.SPECS_LOG }} >> ${{ env.GH_COMMENT_FILE }}
              printf "\n\`\`\`\n" >> ${{ env.GH_COMMENT_FILE }}
          - name: comment PR
            uses: machine-learning-apps/pr-comment@master
            env:
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            with:
              path: Github-comment.md
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this OAS diff tool in golang: https://github.com/Tufin/oasdiff

It outputs json like this:

```
{
 "spec": {
  "paths": {
   "modified": {
    "/": {
     "operations": {
      "modified": {
       "POST": {
        "servers": {
         "added": [
          "https://app.amberflo.io/ingest-endpoint"
         ],
         "deleted": [
          "https://app.amberflo.io/ingest"
         ]
        }
       }
      }
     },
     "servers": {
      "added": [
       "https://app.amberflo.io/ingest-endpoint"
      ],
      "deleted": [
       "https://app.amberflo.io/ingest"
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  },
  "servers": {
   "added": [
    "https://app.amberflo.io/ingest-endpoint"
   ],
   "deleted": [
    "https://app.amberflo.io/ingest"
   ]
  }
 },
 "summary": {
  "diff": true,
  "components": {
   "paths": {
    "modified": 1
   },
   "servers": {
    "added": 1,
    "deleted": 1
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Update:
We added a GitHub action to compare and detect breaking changes: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/openapi-spec-diff